# Initializing POD types with parenthesis in VS 2010 not possible?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I have my pod type :

```
   struct TexImageParams2D
    {
        /*! Width of the texture image */
        GLsizei width;
        /*! Height of the texture image */
        GLsizei height;
        /*! Pointer to image data */
        const GLvoid *pixels;

        /*! For efficiency we don't like to sent texture image over and over again.
         * \param[in] rhs The new texture params which will be compared with this one
         */
        bool operator !=( const TexImageParams2D& rhs )
        {
            return !(width == rhs.width && height == rhs.height && pixels == rhs.pixels);
        }

        /*! We  check is this struct is instantiated with proper values by checking the data pointer  */
        bool isActive()
        {
            return pixels;
        }

        /*! When this class is reseted we use this method to reset vales  */
        void clear()
        {
            width = 0;
            height = 0;
            pixels = nullptr;
        }
    };
```

And that works in gcc 4.8

```
RendererStateTextureUnits::TexImageParams2D temp = RendererStateTextureUnits::TexImageParams2D{ width, height, pixels};
```

But my dear vs 2010 compiler nags like :

```
error C2275: 'Graphics::RendererStateTextureUnits::TexImageParams2D' : illegal use of this type as an expression 
error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{' 
error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'
```

Isn't POD initialization is very old feature even supported in C? Why VS2010 nags about it? If it is VS2010 not supporting this feature from which version Visual Studio begin supporting POD parenthesis initialization?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uniform initialization using curly braces `{}` was introduced in the C++11 standard, which the Visual Studio 2010 compiler does not implement.

Try instead

```
RendererStateTextureUnits::TexImageParams2D temp = { width, height, pixels};
```